# Resizing a turtle.bgpic image

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am creating a program that requires a background image in Python Turtle.
I know how to add the image (bgpic("")) but I need to resize it. I can't use photoshop because I can't then add the file (says that it has no data in the file!).

So how do I resize it through code?

Answer (score 0):

With Pillow you can easily do it :)

here is the doc of the library and the resize function

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=resize#PIL.Image.Image.resize